# limits of number of files in a single directory in unix/linux using Python

Tags: python, linux, unix, file-io, cluster-computing

is it bad to output many files to the same directory in unix/linux? I run thousands of jobs on a cluster and each outputs a file, to one directory.  The upper bound here is around ~50,000 files.  Can IO be limited in speed in light of this?  If so, does the problem go away with a nested directory structure?

Thanks.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

[How many files can I put in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most filesystems store the names of contained files in a list (or some other linear-time access data structure) so storing large numbers of files in a single directory can cause slowness for simple operations like listing.  Having a nested structure can ameliorate this problem by creating a tree structure (or even a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), if it makes sense) of names which can reduce the time it takes to retrieve file stats.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use nested directory structure (ie categorization). You can name them using timestamps, special prefixes for each application etc. This gives you a sense of order when you need to search for specific files and for easier management of your files.