# cakephp: if cache too many page

Tags: cakephp, caching

I want ask : if cache too many page 10000 page is cached.

10000 page create 10000 file cache.
Is it ok ? it can create slow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this could slowdown the application. Modern file systems support big amount of files in a directory. The problem is if you what to manually list all those files.

Answer (score 0):

A cache file is stored on the server as static HTML rather than the dynamically generated HTML code that is created with PHP.

Loading these cache files is significantly quicker than running PHP code through the PHP compiler at runtime.

The only issue is perhaps disk space as the cache files are physical files on the server. Most cache filesizes should be relatively small if used correctly so this really shouldn't be an issue on a proper web server with sufficient resources.

Answer (score 0):

Cache files are generally **always** faster than running the PHP script as they do not have to be processed - the overhead is just hitting the file and retrieving it.

The compromise you make with cache is whether or not your data changes often enough to warrant using file cache, and whether or not users need access to an always up to date file.

I wouldn't worry about it, and hey **you can always turn the cache off** - right?

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, but probably not significant

Full-page cache files are all stored in the same folder. As such caching 10k pages, means having 10k files in a folder. It will not likely be significant, but there will be a slow down in application performance as the cache fills up.

Also note that [there's a limit to how many files you can store in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many) depending on the drive format though generally speaking by the time the limit is reached performance is already significantly affected.

### Don't use view caching if it's not necessary

Even full page caching has a cost. A normal php request is the following logic:

```
user -> internet -> webserver -> php -> (application logic)
```

Using full page view caching this doesn't change much:

```
user -> internet -> webserver -> php -> (read and render cache file)
```

If there is no dynamic content in the cache file it's a better idea to store the contents as a static file and move the response closer to the user:

```
user -> internet -> webserver -> static html file
```

Plugins like [html cache](https://github.com/mcurry/html_cache) permit this by storing cached views as html files and allowing [the webserver to handle requests](https://github.com/mcurry/html_cache/blob/master/extras/webroot.htaccess#L8) before invoking php.

That also means, depending on the cache headers sent for html files, that subsequent requests come straight out of the user's browser cache - and you can't get faster than that:

```
user -> user's browser cache
```