# storing lots of session data

Tags: php, session

I'm just asking this question, is there a cause or problem when storing lots of record or data in session?

```
for example: $_SESSION['rec1'] = rec1; $_SESSION['rec2'] = rec2; $_SESSION['rec3'] = rec3; $_SESSION['rec4'] = rec4; $_SESSION['rec5'] = rec5; etc...
```

is there a problem occur in doing this?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: If it's necessary... Why don't you serialize data on a single session variable and de-serialize if needed?

Comment: Its not a good practice to save lage amount of data in session.In case if you have no other methods use temp tables..

Comment: Please read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274955/are-there-limits-for-session-variables