# Ask about codeigniter session for Cart

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cart

Today I have problem about cart in codeigniter.

At my localhost thats fine when I add some products to the cart bag, no problem detected. But after I upload to the server, I get this problem, I must refresh the page to load products in cart bag. When I remove product from cart bag I get same problem. I must refresh and refresh to view product in the cart bag.

Why this problem occur?

Finally, I solve this problem using PHP Native Session, I replace CI session with PHP Native Session and problem is solved. But, Can that PHP Native session stored in database? like CI Session? as I know, Session just can store max 4kb. I afraid the session can not store all product item in cart bag.

Sorry if my english is bad. :)

I have tried using other browsers like chrome and opera. But the problem still occur.

Thanks for your response friends.. I appreciate it.. :D

You can try it [here](http://dafian.com/dev/webstore/)

Comment: It`s enough...just store the id and quantity

Comment: Have you tried this in more than 1 browser? It could be a browser issue.

Comment: Did you use CI session with database? It uses cookies by default. See "Saving Session Data to a Database" @ http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html CI sessions with DB work well, you just have to set them correctly as described in the link.

Comment: I just cek from firefox desktop and mobile. I get same problem. I'll try using other browser now.

Comment: @Bonatoc I already use CI session with database. That problem still occur.

Comment: `Session just can store max 4kb` No !!! its cookies limit 4kb. can you check console and post if any error ?

Comment: Oh sorry.. Thank for fix my mind @karan thakkar. I guess that session. hahaha..

This mean, session can store unlimited data?

Comment: I have check using other browsers. I use Chrome and opera, but the problem still occur...

Comment: @DafianDR , There's no limit on the amount of data you can store in a session. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274955/are-there-limits-for-session-variables **`Tried and tested`** you must check `memory_limit` for max.

Comment: okey.. this mean it safe to store cart data at session? :)

Answer (score 0):

it is the issue same as code igniter error issue.
it is the redirection problem in your index function of the controller. After remove and add the product redirect at the index function of the controller.
i think you get it.

Comment: function that is called by default. Controller first function.

Comment: This mean I must redirect to first controller after add or remove product? Cannot to cart controller?