# Points about sessions in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

Suppose we have a website with 100k active users.

If we want to save email, name, last name and gender of users in sessions, how much space is allocated to all the sessions?

Are the sessions affecting server RAM, server bandwidth or something else?

Please give me a little information about session functionality and effect of  session overload on the server.

Comment: PHP or ASP.NET? They do not necessarily save stuff in the same way.

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274955/are-there-limits-for-session-variables

Comment: ASP, what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session themselves will consume the server RAM if your mode is set to `InProc`, which is limited only by the amount of RAM available to the worker process.

Considering your high demand, you want to be really careful what you're putting in the session, only when it's **absolutely necessary**. Don't put things in session and leave them there for use in a page or two, just go back to the database and get them, otherwise your session size will creep up drastically.

Based on what you're storing, it's only 5kb or even less, so based on 100k users, that would be:

```
5kb * 100,000 = 488.28MB
```

So you see, even though you're only storing a couple of details, at that level of usage the memory usage is quite significant.

For such high demand and usage, I would consider using a dedicated state server (`StateServer` mode) which allows you to manage it separately and allocate the resources to that server as required.

The other option is using SQL Server session (`SQLServer` mode) which is limited only by the size that is available to the database. So we're talking hard disk space here and not RAM. To be honest though, if you're going to the database to retrieve your session information, then why not just go to the database and retrieve the information you need anyway?

Comment: suppose i want to store an object with these parameters : email, name , last name, each one is 100 character. what's size of the session with this situation?

Comment: @rezayegane Let's assume 100 bytes for 100 characters (as per UTF-8), then that'd be 300 bytes per user, which results in a session size of 28.61MB for 100,000 users.

Comment: @rezayegane It's not quite as simple as just calculating active users times session storage. One client can spawn several sessions, and they will often stay in memory long after the user has turned "inactive". I would say approximately 1-1.5k depending on overhead and bit-allocation. Consider storing such data in _database_, _hidden form elements_, _cache_, etc. There are many better options.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**

This answer was posted when the OP asked about php and asp.net

---

> Are the sessions affecting server RAM, server bandwidth or something
>   else?

Sessions are affecting server [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory)

> Please give me a little information about session functionality and
>   effect of session overload on the server.

If the effect of sessions overload the server, the server will run slow because of the usage of the RAM.

Most of the settings of sessions can be changed in the **php.ini** file

If you want to know more about session functionality, you should check out [the pages about sessions on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or even the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29).

There is too much information about sessions to actually post in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store such data in the client when you have 100k users. Your pages will be larger and require more bandwidth but you will allocate less memory on the server. 
If you talking about a ASP-application check this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416137/Understanding-Session-Management-Techniques-in-ASP