# Is there any limit on numbers to define sessions

Tags: php

I am making a program in which I need to remember a lot number of things (about 20-30 values at a time). For which I am using sessions.

I just want to know is there any problem in defining large number of sessions. Is there any limit on numbers to define sessions.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274955/are-there-limits-for-session-variables

Comment: follow the above mentioned link that mentioned by @Saty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no limit to store the number of variables. Also, there's no limit on the amount of data you can store in a session.

Comment: you can follow this link: contains amazing information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274955/are-there-limits-for-session-variables