# How many files can a folder hold in an ext3 filesystem?

Tags: linux, ext3

Question says it all.

Is there a limit of files a folder can have? 
if not, will there be implications if a folder holds too many files? if so, how many is too many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Please see [How many files in a directory is too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many) -- note [dir_index](http://lonesysadmin.net/2007/08/17/use-dir_index-for-your-new-ext3-filesystems/), claims an upper-bound on files in directory. Then see [Ext3 – handling large number of files in a directory](http://roopindersingh.com/2008/05/10/ext3-handling-large-number-of-files-in-a-directory/) and the bad performance when not using dir_index :-)

---

[Wiki: EXT3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) seems to indicate it's "unlimited". One disadvantage of "too many" files is with programs that aren't designed to work with with so many files -- for instance a GUI that "locks up" while trying to load the directory contents.

Since the underlying storage is a B-tree variant, [looking up *a specific file name* is generally fast](http://ext2.sourceforge.net/2005-ols/paper-html/node3.html). (This also covers issues with `readdir`.)

Happy coding.

---

For what it's worth, proxies (like Squid), use multi-level directory structures by default. Then again, the amount of expected cache files is rather large compared to the number of say, documents, a normal user may have :)

Comment: Thank you. There'll be no GUIs as this is on a remote web server.