# What is the best way to store user uploaded files in a website?

Tags: file, web, storage

I'm trying to create a website in which I need to store a few user uploaded files (like some profile images, some xml files etc).

So what is the best way to store those files?

Currently, I'm creating a new directory on the server for every new user registered and storing the files for each user in their respective directory but someone told me it's not the best way.

So, how do I store those files? Whether I create a common directory & name the files as per the user-id or something related to the user OR keep creating a new directory for every user??

Comment: Did they explain their concern? My concern would be if others had access to the uploaded information b/c they knew the location. If the directory were /protected/user/ and the information could only be accessed through a PHP that would resolve my only concern.

Comment: That is indeed one big concern but right now, the user uploaded files with my application can be public so I don't need to worry about those at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workable solution will depend on your requirements, e.g. how many users are you expecting. A one-directory-per-user solution might hit some filesystem limitations soon (for ext3, the max number of subdirectories in one directory is fixed to 32000).

One-file-per-user should be ok for a long while (see: [How many files in a directory is too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many)).

Finally, if your userbase grows you could use a fixed number of shards (e.g. based on the userid) to limit both the number of directories and the number of files per directory (as an example for this, see [how git stores its objects in loose format](http://web.archive.org/web/20120211182825/http://book.git-scm.com/7_how_git_stores_objects.html)).

Answer (score 4):

Well you have a few options.

1. You can store them as files on the file system, outside the web root.
2. You can store them as binary data in a standard RMDBS like MySQL.
3. You can use a "NoSQL" database like CouchDB or Redis which are specialized in storing documents.

The best way will depend on your application, timeframe, and your experience. Option 1 would probably be the easiest. Option 2 would probably be the most flexible. Option 3 would likely be the best performing if it meets the needs of your documents.

Comment: I'm not sure Redis is specialized at storing documents -- Redis is primarily a key:value store.  When the term 'document' is used in NoSQL database discussions, people typically mean a data object, not something like an XML file.  Then again, I've never heard of storing a file's binary data in a database so I suppose it's possible.

Comment: Here is my source for Redis storing documents. http://images.infoworld.com/d/data-explosion/no-sql-new-databases-new-applications-400?page=0,3 I will admit I've never used either. I have stored files in the database. in PHP you use a BLOB field and use pack() to convert the string binary. I've also used a method much like GIT where I used the userid, padded it to 0000003450 and then created the directory: /00/00/00/34/50/