# No space left on device- Ubuntu Issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I am getting this error "**OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device**" when I am writing files in a directory. I am downloading images programmatically from different sources and creating directories according to day wise. Its working well on windows though.

While checking **inodes** I got this

[image]

I tried different solution like deleting the deleting the junk file and tmp folder but still no success.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

inodes don't directly correlate with disk usage. Better use `df -h` to actually see, if your drive is full.

But as you get the error: Yep, it's full. Up to the brim.

You probably have some data some where that uses all that precious storage. Check your home directory with `du -hs  * | sort -h`. This can take a moment, but it will show you the size of all files and directories in the current workdir (and sort it too).

Also directories to check would be `/opt`, `/var` and `/tmp`. Don't randomly delete stuff in `/var` though, if you don't know what you are doing.

I've listed `/tmp` here too, because you don't have listed it as a mount of the type `tmpfs`. You should fix that probably.

Comment: my drive is not full, it has a lot of space. Check https://ibb.co/cwvsHjy
also by checking the directories (https://ibb.co/9s1q1hT) , its only the /var folder that is having files with bigger size like the log etc. Is it safe to delete file from this directory?

Comment: Ok, than i would ask you to update your question with an explanation. What you are actually doing, when you get this error. Also please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6999259/3939085 for maybe some explanations.

Comment: question updated. I am downloading images programmatically within different directories