# Thousands of user image uploads in one directory?

Tags: php, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many files in a directory is too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many)

I built custom software for an industry networking site using Doctrine ORM and Smarty.

My question is this, I just launched, and I have all image uploads going to:

```
/images/ - for the full size images
/images/thumbs/
/images/thumbs-mid/
/images/thumbs-small/
```

I've already got 50MB in image uploads in only 45 minutes. Is it a bad idea to let thousands of images pile up in one directory? Or should they be broken up into more directories? What do you suggest?

Thanks for any advice

- Linux CENTOS 5 64bit

Comment: depending on os\file-system there are limits to how many files you can have in a directory

Answer (score -4):

I suggest you set a max size on image uploads and store them as blobs or binary data types in a relational database, this way you can keep more meta data about the image such as the user who uploaded how many times its been viewed and for db replication its a lot easier to backup a single db. I know MySQL supports this and although I'm not a fan of Microsoft they have a free edition of SQL Server Express that performs very well for storing and getting images from the db. If you decide to go the route of a file system you might also run into concurrency issues which a db will take care of for you.

Comment: No, no. Store the images in a file directory, your os could have limits as @Dagon mentioned, then use sql to store meta info and a reference to the image location.