# Codeigniter page caching: Is 24Gb of cache files too much?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I am running a Codeigniter application that uses page cache with ~350k files and take up ~26Gb of disk space in ONE folder. Is that too much?

Comment: Yes, in general it is too much. what you're doing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, CI puts each page cache in a single folder. Assuming you are a FAT32 Linux machine, and the files aren't grouped into sub-folders I imagine you may be taking a performance hit.

Referencing this; [How many files can I put in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many)

A reasonable solution could be to override the default caching library to group things into folders (perhaps based on the first N of the hash name) to improve performance.