# How many files per folder in CentOS Linux 6 x64 OS

Tags: linux, centos

I'm working on a website right now that will likely to contain more than 60,000 images + they thumbnails. Now, those images are distributed in the 4000 posts that I have. Each post has a folder.

Let's provide an example: 
`waterfalls-mexico/` -> will contain about 50 images
`waterfalls-peru/ ->` will contain about 200 images
`waterfalls[4000]/` etc etc 
Because I have 4000 posts... each post has a folder and in each folder, the images of the post. I have all the folders in a root one.

I know It will be hard to list all the directories, but since I have the path of the images in a database, I just call the images with the direct path. Am I going to have any performance issues by calling images that are stored in this specific way? I use CentOS Linux 6 x64 OS.

Comment: its going to be hard to predict the performance without knowing what the hardware is , the size of image and so on. I would suggest running it on a env similar to production enviornment and measure the latency and page load times and optimize it from then on by adding caches and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many files can I put in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory)