# How to optimize sub folder generation for a FILESTREAM-Enabled sql server Database?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am familiarizing with [FILESTREAM-Enabled sql server Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645585.aspx). Considering Microsoft's query to create the database, it becomes clear there obviously needs to be some a folder where to put files after database creation: the **filestream1** folder. Such a folder needs to be in an existing **data** folder

```
CREATE DATABASE Archive ON
PRIMARY ( NAME = Arch1,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archdat1.mdf'),
FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM( NAME = Arch3,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\filestream1')
LOG ON  ( NAME = Archlog1,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archlog1.ldf')
GO
```

This seems quite obvious. However, for performance reasons it is essential that new sub folders inside **filestream1** are created automatically once the number of inserted files grows to high. If this doesn't happen, the number of files in a folder grows higher and higher and the performance of my server becomes slower and slower. [Moreover, the number of files in a folder is limited anyway depending on the used file system of my customer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466596/1987258).

Is there a way to trigger or configure automatic sub folder creation for a FILESTREAM-Enabled sql server Database?