# Upload images based on matching field and image name

Tags: django

I'm building an inventory list that includes the fields listed below in my **Django** model. I have a folder full of images that the name of the images correspond to the the `Item Number`. For install, the item number may be **4119**, then the image file name will be **4119.jpg**.

I would like to write a script that iterated over the items in the database and uploads the corresponding image. Any thoughts on where to start are greatly appreciated.

```
from django.db import models

def directory_path(instance, filename):
    return '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(supplier.name, pricelist.item_number, filename)

class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PriceList(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey('Supplier', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    case_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    piece_list_amount = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    partner_list_amount = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory_path)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_number
```

Comment: Keep in mind btw the amount of files in a directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory

Comment: @AndreyShipilov Something I would have never considered! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my code and implement exactly what you need ... I hope this will be helpful for you:

```
import os
from Project.settings import BASE_DIR
from apps.showcase.models import Product
from django.core.files import File

obj_id_to_img_filename_mapping = (
    (175, 'full_ef58c1a5af252d4459055481b1bbfa76.jpg'),
    (176, 'full_2111856a6a092a3c65639aff56070aef.jpg'),
    (177, 'full_b8154e9b348561ee295c2d1651ecca3c.gif'),
    # ...
)


def update_product_images():
    print('Starting upload products images...\n')
    for product_id, file_name in obj_id_to_img_filename_mapping:
        if file_name:
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)

            absolute_filename = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps/showcase/static/showcase/images/initial_data/product', file_name)
            local_file = open(absolute_filename, 'r')
            django_file = File(local_file)

            product.image.save(file_name, django_file, save=True)

            print(absolute_filename + '\n')
```

Comment: My app has a folder of jpgs, so how would I match 4119.jpg to the 4119 items in the database?

Comment: Just filter by `item_number` instead of get object by `pk` in this example ... If you are new to Django - please complete official tutorial :)