# Is the server load affected by the number of images in a directory?

Tags: image, server

Is it true that large directories can cause the increased I/O wait ?
I was told to put not more than 1000 images per directory.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends somewhat on the OS and the filesystem - some handle large numbers of files better than others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!!

you can divide files in sub directories under main directory... it make IO to find files faster...

max file limit may differ with file system you are using you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466596/5357992) 
you can divide your file/folder structure as per need.
 1000 to 3000 is good number if you are going to have a lot of files

Comment: update the answer...
number is actually may differ as per your need and the same rule applies to directories as well(there should not be more directory in one directory)