# How to group glyphs by unicode ranges

Tags: fontforge

I am new to FontForge. When creating new fonts, I know there are two ways to set a project: one is a single `.sfd` files, which could be too large; the other is a `.sfdir` folder, but may contain too many files. I want to group the glyphs by unicode ranges, so there can be only a certain number of (not so large) files. How can I do that?

Comment: What is too large? Too large for what? What are too many files? Too many for what? Do you have errors?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory

Comment: By saying "too large" or "too many", I mean it's difficult for me to manage them. I know I *can* do that, but I *dislike* it.

Comment: Without you explaining what your pain point actually is, it's hard to help. I've had trouble with version control in the past, somewhat alleviated by choosing a better Git client, but it's still complex to track changes across so many glyphs. What do you mean by "manage"?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the only two options: single file or single directory. I don't recommend splitting into multiple fonts, as it would be much harder to manage font-wide features including kerning.

You could perhaps save as sfdir then create a parallel directory structure containing shortcuts or symlinks to the individual glyph files. But without knowing what your pain point is I can't say if this would be useful or worth the effort.