# How to count all the subdirectories that are present in a directory?

Tags: c

In this code, I am getting all the subdirectories paths from a directory. It is working fine but I want to add something more and that is to count all the subdirectories and print them. How to do this in this function. I used the `count` variable to make it work but the result is like this.

**Given result:**

```
/home/runner/TestC1/file
15775232
/home/runner/TestC1/dsf
15775233
/home/runner/TestC1/main.c
15775234
/home/runner/TestC1/main
15775235
```

**Expected result:**

```
/home/runner/TestC1/file
/home/runner/TestC1/dsf
/home/runner/TestC1/main.c
/home/runner/TestC1/main

Counted: 4 subdirectories.
```

**Code**

```
void listdir(void){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    size_t count;

    if (!(dir = opendir(path))) {  
        perror ("opendir-path not found");
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {  
        char *name = entry->d_name;
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)  
            if (!strcmp(name, ".") || !strcmp(name, ".."))
                continue;
        snprintf (path1, 100, "%s/%s\n", path, name);
        printf("%s", path1);
        printf("%zu\n", count);
        count++;
    }
    closedir (dir); 
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `count`. And you are printing inside the loop.

Comment: You should only count directories according to the title of the question.  You code counts every file as well as sub-directories.  Put an else block after the inner if and increment count there.  Initialize `count` too, as already pointed out.  IMO, you need braces after the outer `if` too.  The current nested if could (maybe even should) be written as `if (A && (B || C))`, but you're about to need to change it so that you do need the two levels of operation.

Comment: `"opendir-path not found"` is going to lead to very confusing error messages like `opendir-path not found: permission denied`.  Just write `perror(path);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14637/thomas) says [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318074/how-to-count-all-the-subdirectories-that-are-present-in-a-directory#comment117244739_66318074):

> You didn't initialize count. And you are printing inside the loop

1. You do not initialize `count` to zero.
2. You print inside the loop.
3. You count everything except `.` and `..`, without checking whether it is a file or a directory

Here's a (hopefully) fixed version of your code

```
void listdir(void){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    unsigned count = 0;

    if (!(dir = opendir(path))) {  
        perror ("opendir-path not found");
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {  
        char *name = entry->d_name;
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            if (!strcmp(name, ".") || !strcmp(name, ".."))
                continue;
            count++;
            snprintf (path1, 100, "%s/%s\n", path, name);
            printf("%s", path1);
        }
    }
    printf("\nCounted: %u subdirectories.\n", count);
    closedir (dir); 
}
```

Edit:
Edited my code following the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318074/how-to-count-all-the-subdirectories-that-are-present-in-a-directory#comment117245877_66318245) by [chux-ReinstateMonica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica)

> Minor: Little reason for size_t count when unsigned count is certainly fine. size_t depends on memory - not file space. Pedantically could use uintmax_t. IAC, "%d" is not the specified matching specifier to go with size_t - a step backwards from OP's matching "%zu"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you, was used to using `size_t` for any unsigned data.
(Assuming he isn't working on a filesystem from some martian futuristic civilization where file you store billions of files in the same directory, I doubt `uintmax_t` is absolutely necessary)

Comment: [How many files can I put in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466521/2410359) might be an interesting read to assess the type for `count`.