# use of df.coalesce(1) in csv vs delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

When saving to a delta table we avoid 'df.coalesce(1)' but when saving to csv or parquet we(my team) add 'df.coalesce(1)'. Is it a common practise? Why? Is it mandatory?

Comment: Based on my opinion, Delta format has [auto optimize and auto compact](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/auto-optimize.html) builtin. Using `coalesce(1)` will merge all files into one and after save, auto compact will do the same job. Any other format you must write that you want to keep only 1 file.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases when I have seen `df.coalesce(1)` it was done to generate only one file, for example, import CSV file into Excel, or for Parquet file into the Pandas-based program.  But if you're doing `.coalesce(1)`, then the write happens via single task, and it's becoming the performance bottleneck because you need to get data from other executors, and write it.

If you're consuming data from Spark or other distributed system, having multiple files will be beneficial for performance because you can write & read them in parallel. By default, Spark writes N files into the directory where N is the number of partitions.  As [@pltc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3441510/pltc) noticed, this may generate the big number of files that's often not desirable because you'll get performance overhead from accessing them.  So we need to have a balance between the number of files and their size - for Parquet and Delta (that is based on Parquet), having the bigger files bring several performance advantages - you read less files, you can get better compression for data inside the file, etc.

For Delta specifically, having `.coalesce(1)` having the same problem as for other file formats - you're writing via one task.  Relying on default Spark behaviour and writing multiple files is beneficial from performance point of view - each node is writing its data in parallel, but you can get too many small files (so you may use `.coalesce(N)` to write bigger files).  For Databricks Delta, as it was correctly pointed by [@Kafels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6080276/kafels), there are [some optimizations](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/auto-optimize.html) that will allow to remove that `.coalesce(N)` and do automatic tuning achieve the best throughput (so called "Optimized Writes"), and create bigger files ("Auto compaction") - but they should be used carefully.

Overall, the topic of optimal file size for Delta is an interesting topic - if you have big files (1Gb is used by default by OPTIMIZE command), you can get better read throughput, but if you're rewriting them with MERGE/UPDATE/DELETE, then big files are bad from performance standpoint, and it's better to have smaller (16-64-128Mb) files, so you can rewrite less data.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: it's not mandatory, it depends on the size of your dataframe.

**Long answer**:

If your dataframe is 10Mb, and you have 1000 partitions for example, each file would be about 10Kb. And having so many small files would reduce Spark performance dramatically, not to mention when you have too many files, you'll eventually reach [OS limitation of the number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory). Any how, when your dataset is **small enough**, you should merge them into a couple of files by `coalesce`.

However, if your dataframe is 100G, technically you still can use `coalesce(1)` and save to a single file, but later on you will have to deal with less parallelism when reading from it.